# Локальное тестирование yandex maps API 3

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить доступ к API 3 с локального dev сервера, если для работы API необходимо указать разрешенные домены (Referer) для ключа, а локальный сервер имеет только ip, который там нельзя указать.

Вариант с указанием алиаса для локалхоста (127.0.0.1) в hosts работает только для машины, на которой расположен сервер, а хотелось бы более универсальный вариант, чтобы тестировать приложение подключаясь к серверу с телефона

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант использовать [Referer Control](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin?hl=ru) для Google Chrome для подмены Referer

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но данный способ больше для десктопа. На мобильном устройстве не на каждый браузер получится поставить расширение и не получится поставить на webview

Comment: На Я.Бро сработало

Comment: В таком случае как вариант раньше можно было в целом убрать referer для localhost и использовать любой валидный ключ.

Comment: Возможно правильным путём было бы обратиться в поддержку яндекса для разъяснения ситуации с тестированием.